# Switch parent and child process

Tags: c++, fork, parent-child

I am wondering whether it is possible to transform a child process (created via fork) into the parent process?

I want to implement a transaction concept in which each transaction forks a snapshot of the current memory state. If a transaction commits successfully, the corresponding process should become the new parent process and the old parent process should be terminated.

Is that possible at all?

Comment: It is totally useless! If you want to use memory from another "process" think about threading.

Comment: You need to notify process to terminate. There are many ways to do so, including standard IO, sending a signal, using [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory_%28interprocess_communication%29) or [unix domain sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket), etc.

Comment: @Klaus: By forking a child process, you can just kill the child if the transaction cannot be committed. No changes will affect the memory of the main process then. 

What happens when I kill the parent process? I think the child process will be killed, too, won't it?

Comment: Transaction? Sorry, what is a transaction for a process? `What happens when I kill the parent process?` The child becomes a child of the init process. No need to kill the child here! But you are talking of 'memory state' which makes no sense for processes, because child and parent have full individual memory areas. That this is optimized with "copy on write" and other techniques is not important here. Both processes can not access the memory of the other process.

Comment: I want to experiment whether snapshot isolation for database transactions can be implemented in such a way (main-memory DBMS). Anyways, thanks for the comments.